# PHP - Как удалить весь код, кроме <table>…</table>?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В PHP не силён вовсе. Знаю, что вопрос решается через preg_replace, но как точно?

Есть код:

```
<div class="product_photos">
    <a href="img/prod_1.jpg"><img src="img/prod_1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="img/prod_1.jpg"><img src="img/prod_1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="img/prod_1.jpg"><img src="img/prod_1.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div class="product_left">
    <table class="hars_table">
        <tr>
            <th>МОДЕЛЬ</th>
            <td>Carry 105 base</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Грузоподъёмность, кг</th>
            <td>500</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="product_right">
    <p>какой-то большой текст.</p>
</div>
```

Как должна быть написана регулярка, чтобы удалить весь код вокруг таблицы?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По=хорошему, надо бы html parser пользовать

```
$dom = new domDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$table = $dom->getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

echo $dom->saveHTML($table);
```

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек! Правда при этом ломается кодировка кириллицы, поэтому добавил перед импортом: $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8');

Answer (score 3):

Убирает весь код вокруг первого найденного table:

```
<?php

$text = <<<'EOD'
<div class="product_photos">
    <a href="img/prod_1.jpg"><img src="img/prod_1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="img/prod_1.jpg"><img src="img/prod_1.jpg"></a>
    <a href="img/prod_1.jpg"><img src="img/prod_1.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div class="product_left">
    <table class="hars_table">
        <tr>
            <th>МОДЕЛЬ</th>
            <td>Carry 105 base</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Грузоподъёмность, кг</th>
            <td>500</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="product_right">
    <p>какой-то большой текст.</p>
</div>
EOD;

$matches = [];

if (preg_match('/<table(?:.*?)>(?:.*?)<\/table>/sm', $text, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[0];
}
```